# Need help with MPV bash script

Tags: bash, screenshot, filename

Basically I'm Try to edit a bash script. To goal of the Script is to allow me to take a bunch of screenshot of videos by Simply launching it from terminal with only having to specify the Filename and the Number screenshot desired. I've worked out a few bugs but I'm having issues with getting MPV to assign the filename I want.

Here's the script as it stands currently.

```
#!/bin/bash


### Global variables
filename="$1"

### Error handling
if [ -z ${filename} ]; 
then
    echo "ERROR: No video file supplied. Please enter a video file as argument."
    exit 1;
fi

NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS=9
if [ ! -z $2 ]; 
then
  NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS=$2
  echo "WARNING: Overwrite default number of screenshots to ${NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS}."
  sleep 3s
fi




# Get the total length of the video in seconds.
#  Use mplayer to display the info of the video and then get the value of ID_LENGTH, the total number of seconds of the video.
total_length=$(mplayer -identify -frames 0 -vc null -vo null -ao null "$filename" | grep ID_LENGTH | sed 's/ID_LENGTH=//' | sed 's/\..*//')
# Reference https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/TOOLS/mpv_identify.sh

# Remove 4 seconds from the video so that it doesn't take screenshot at the ends.
let total_length-=4

# time_slice: At which time interval should mplayer take screenshots.
let time_slice=${total_length}/${NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS}

# time_at: When should mplayer take screenshots.
time_at=${time_slice};

# Looping to take screenshots.
for ((i=1; i <= NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS ; i++))
do


  # Take the screenshot.
  #mplayer -loop 1 -nosound -frames 1 -ss ${time_at} -vo png:z=9 ${filename}
  mpv --quiet --no-audio --vo=image --screenshot-template="%f %n" --start=${time_at} --frames=1 "$filename" 

  # Increment to the next time slice.
  let time_at+=${time_slice}



done
```

Comment: The script looks good (haven't tried it) but to what filename are you referring in your question ? Surely not the `$filename` parameter in the script ? Can you clarify ?

Comment: Do you have a message after each screenshot like `Exiting... (End of file)`?

Comment: Well I eventually got it to do what i wanted on my own.  I simply needed a way to create unique filenames for the Images created because otherwise rerunning the script always overwrote the last set. This issue was moving 0000001.jpeg to a unique filename so it woulnd be overwrote. I eventually  used this line to solve it mv "$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )/"00000001.* ~/Pictures/${padding}.$$ I made a few other changes to it as made obvius by the extra additions there. I

Comment: A.B. I did but when the script was running (before i fixed it) the next screenshot would fire off before mv could trigger so i had to add a few stops to it. otherwise the end line wouldn't show as it didn't run right.  that's what eventually helped me work out most of the bugs.

Comment: If the answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script can't work in this way. The script is mostly fine, although you should make minor improvements (Use [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) for that.)

The problem is, `mpv` uses an internal counter for the naming of the screenshot file (`%n`). And the counter is reseted at each pass of the loop.

The modified script below renames the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

### Global variables
filename="$1"

### Error handling
if [ -z "${filename}" ]; 
then
    echo "ERROR: No video file supplied. Please enter a video file as argument."
    exit 1;
fi

NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS=9
if [ ! -z "$2" ]; 
then
  NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS=$2
  echo "WARNING: Overwrite default number of screenshots to ${NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS}."
  sleep 3s
fi

# Get the total length of the video in seconds.
#  Use mplayer to display the info of the video and then get the value of ID_LENGTH, the total number of seconds of the video.
total_length=$(mplayer -identify -frames 0 -vc null -vo null -ao null "$filename" | grep ID_LENGTH | sed 's/ID_LENGTH=//' | sed 's/\..*//')
# Reference https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/TOOLS/mpv_identify.sh

# Remove 4 seconds from the video so that it doesn't take screenshot at the ends.
let total_length-=4

# time_slice: At which time interval should mplayer take screenshots.
let time_slice=${total_length}/${NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS}

# time_at: When should mplayer take screenshots.
time_at=${time_slice};

# Looping to take screenshots.
for ((i=1; i <= NUM_OF_SCREENSHOTS ; i++))
do

  # Take the screenshot.
  #mplayer -loop 1 -nosound -frames 1 -ss ${time_at} -vo png:z=9 ${filename}
  mpv --quiet --no-audio --vo=image --start=${time_at} --frames=1 "$filename" 
  rename 's/^[0-9]+/out'"${time_at}"'/' 00000001.jpg

  # Increment to the next time slice.
  let time_at+=${time_slice}

done

exit 0
```